# Alert dialog resizes when the content is changed

Tags: android, dialog, resize, height, alert

I have this `AlertDialog` with and dynamic list in it(when a item from the list is selected the content of the list changes also). The problem is that initial the dialog 's height matches its parent but when the content is changed and the size is much smaller the dialog wraps the content. how can i avoid this?

```
public ExplorerDialog(Context context, final SettingsDialog settingsDialog, int fileType) {  
    super(context); 

    setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_explorer_file_manager); 
    setTitle("Explorer Dialog"); 
    setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_explorer_layout, null)); 
    setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            settingsDialog.show(); 
        } 
    }); 

    setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            settingsDialog.show(); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code, such as how you build your `AlertDialog`

Comment: public ExplorerDialog(Context context, final SettingsDialog settingsDialog, int fileType) {  super(context);
  
  setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_explorer_file_manager);
  setTitle("Explorer Dialog");
  setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_explorer_layout, null));
  setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    settingsDialog.show();
   }
  });
  setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    settingsDialog.show();
  }});}

Answer (score 1):

you've probably set the view of your alertdialog to the list, here's a quick way to get what you want:

```
 d.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600)
```

where d is the created dialog, this allows you to set values for the width and height.

Comment: d is supposed to be my alert dialog? i already tried that and is still resizing

Answer (score 0):

your cusyom dialog layout :

```
LinearLayout dialoglayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglayout);

dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,1100));
```

or

if you want width of screen size:

```
dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1100));
```